# Trying to make a basic if then but really nothing I've read is helping me. Please help!

Tags: variables, if-statement, toggle

I've been working on this script for about two hours straight and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've never used variables in jquery before, and all of the guides I'm reading show variables but not used in any useful context. Here is my code:

```
    var $a = 1;
    var $b = 1;

    $('#pdnav1').click(function(){
        if($a == $b) {
            var $a = 0;
            $('#pdbgimg').html('<img id="pdimg" src="http://royalty-ro.com/forums/uploads/images/1303326955-U1.jpg">'); 
            $('#pd1').fadeIn(0);
            $('#pdbg1').animate({top: '0px'});
        }else{
            var $a = 1;
            $('.pdhide').animate({
              top: '-200px'
            });
            $('.pdhide2').delay(400).fadeOut(0);
        }
    });
```

Mainly all I want to to do is the "if" statement the first time I click it, and then the "else" statement the next time (repeating this process each time you click it, just like a toggle).

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a `$a` variable inside your function :

```
var $a = 0;
```

That declaration, inside the function, overrides the global `$a` variable that's defined outside of the function.

If you want to use global variables, and access them inside functions, don't re-define them using `var` inside that function.

For more informations, you should read about [**Variable Scope**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Variable_Scope).

And, btw : using `$` in variables names is generally not quite considered as a good idea...

Comment: I need to modify the variable A inside of my function so the next time I click the button it will have a different action, how can I do that without over-riding the initial variable declaration?

Comment: This is what I have now, its still not working:


  `$('#pdnav1').click(function(){
   if(a == "no") {
   $('.pdhide').animate({top:'-200px'},500);
   $('.pdhide2').delay(500).fadeOut(0);
   $('.pdbgimghide').delay(0).fadeOut(0);
   a = "yes";
   }else{
   $('#pd1').delay(0).fadeIn(0);
   $('#pdbgimg1').delay(0).fadeIn(0);
   $('#pdbg1').animate({top: '0px'},500);
   a = "no";
   }
  });
`

@pascal martin

Comment: I defined the variable outside of my coding, with a onready statement further down. Thanks for your help :D